# LaTeX Error: "cmap.sty" not found

Tags: errors, lyx

Could anybody help me with my situation.

When I try to see my Lyx document in pdf Lyx write this Error note

```
"LaTeX Error: "cmap.sty" not found"
```

and in description

```
"*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)".
```

What could I do with it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `cmap.sty` in TeX Live 2011 dates from 2008 and is also (in a different version) in a TeX Live 2007 that I keep for archival. So you need to load the corresponding package in your distribution: one needs to know at least what operating system you're using.

Comment: NoT a ReAl QuEsTiOn